# how to disable v-model input in Vue from mutating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I've a code for calculating coin amount from an array, this code allows me to learn how much i can buy from a table with given order, in code orderSize is mutating inorder to reach result but when i put an input area for manual entering ordersize that mutating causes input text to change(if it is higher than first item amount), i dont want text to change.
I tried adding another variable that equals to orderSize but same thing happens. What should i do to prevent input text to be mutated.
(Try entering any value higher than 100 text will change)
(array is coming from outsource i cant control)
(If i dont mutate that variable my main goal calculating coin amount cant be accomplished)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teramit/861ca4tk/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    orderSize : null,
  },
  computed: {
    calculateOrder () {
      var coinArray = [["100","1"],["200","2"],["300","3"],["400","4"], 
      ["500","5"],["600","6"]] ;
      var sum = 0
      var sum1 = 0
      var i= 0
      
      for (i = 0; i < coinArray.length; i++){
        if (coinArray[i][0]*coinArray[i][1] < this.orderSize) {
          sum1 += parseFloat(coinArray[i][1]);
          sum += coinArray[i][0]*coinArray[i][1];
          this.orderSize -= coinArray[i][0]*coinArray[i][1] ;        
        } else {
          return sum1+this.orderSize/parseFloat(coinArray[i][0]);
        }
      }
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <input v-model="orderSize" placeholder="Order $">
  <p>{{ calculateOrder }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, the problem is that you are modifying `orderSize` by using `-=`, which will show up in the input.

If you want to avoid this, then first copy the value of `orderSize` to a new variable, e.g.:

```
// Copy the variable
let size = this.orderSize
for (...){
  if (...) {
    size -= coinArray[i][0]*coinArray[i][1];
  } else {
     return sum1+size/parseFloat(coinArray[i][0]);
  }
```

(I have removed unrelated code, and contents of `if`/`for` for clarity).